# I want to concat 1 value for 3 rows in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a df that goes like this:

```
#copy and paste this code to display the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame( {0: {'steps': 16.0, 'speed': 0.0, 'pace': 6.031605943421883}, 1: {'steps': 21.0, 'speed': 0.0, 'pace': 6.031605943421883}, 2: {'steps': 10.0, 'speed': 0.0, 'pace': 5.362233184974702}, 3: {'steps': 9.0, 'speed': 9.947599455736407, 'pace': 5.267776883282379}, 4: {'steps': 3.0, 'speed': 9.947599455736407, 'pace': 5.203732212343261}, 5: {'steps': 8.0, 'speed': 11.189367923820171, 'pace': 5.1973026126343065}} )
```

df has 3 rows, so I want to concat the corresponding day(in timestamp) for these 3 rows:

```
#day that corresponds to the 3 lines in df
a = pd.Series(1594759248000)

#replicating this day 3 times
a = a.loc[a.index.repeat(3)].reset_index(drop=True)

#concatenating the values
df = pd.concat([a,df])
```

But this code returns me a df with 6 rows: 3 rows with the repeated corresponding day and 3 rows with the values that were in the original `df`

I want a `df` with the same 3 rows. But with a columns with this `a` timestamp for each row of the original df

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just `df["a"] = 1594759248000`?

Comment: This wouldn't solve the problem by itself, but it helped me to understand a better way to do that. Instead of replicating ``a`` I just used ``a[0]`` and it worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets `assign`; to create a new column, `**a.to_frame('date').iloc[0]` to create df from series, unpack and parse the contents in the new column being created.

```
df=df.assign(**a.to_frame('date').iloc[0])
```

Comment: This also worked, but just using ``a[0]`` worked well too. Thanks